# On Unity 2018.1 Android gradle build failing with 'library uses same package'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build, build.gradle

This issue appears after update to Unity 2018.1. On 2017.3.1 version everything worked fine. 
Gradle version: 3.3 
Android Plugin version: 2.3.3

Does anyone have an idea how to fix following error?

```
 CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity2018\Editor
 \Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" 
 org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ': processReleaseResources'.
 > Error: A library uses the same package as this project: com.unity3d.player
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by Simple Android Notifications Free asset (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/simple-android-notifications-free-68626).

AndroidManifest file in simple-android-notifications.aar contains package="com.unity3d.player"

After renaming it to "com.hippogames.simpleandroidnotifications" I now able to build APK.

The strange thing is that the same library was successfully used with Unity 2017.3.1 and plugin worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I tried million things, but only this solved my problem:
When adding facebook sdk package to assets, it creates Facebook SDK folder, and plugins are in it. So : 
1. I moved everything from inside Facebook SDK folder to Assets folder. 
2. Then I go to Assets/PlayServicesResolver/AndroidResolver/Force Resolve (Don't know if this is necessary).
It appears that unity couldn't find the path to plugins for android. I lost 5 days in searching the solution.

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps and rebuild the project

1. Goto File from unity top Menu
2. Select Build Settings
3. From Build Setting click on Player Settings
4. In Player Setting Inspector Menu Select Other Settings
5. See for Identification->Package Name
6. change Package Name to something unique like com.yourname.appname

and save the project and build again

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this did not help. I've already had unique name for package, but even with a newer different one it still throws the same error.